# What is the best way to detect collisions with byte array terrain

Tags: c#, arrays, unity-game-engine, graph, collision-detection

I have a multi dimensional byte array (x,y,z) which describes the terrain in my game, for example if the byte has value 0 it is air(passable terrain) and if the value is 4 it is rock(solid block).

Now I am starting to code the movement of my character by looking up the cell I want to move to and allow movement if the cell has value 0 and prevent movement if it is 4.

However I've run into a problem which is that some of my characters are wider than 1 cell unit, so for a character that is 3x3 cells wide I now have to check for collisions with the array on 9 points each time I want to move the character( I tried checking only the 4 corners but it allowed the character to go through 1x1 blocks since the center of the character was no longer being checked for collisions)

However the problem goes deeper since I also have to check for height now I need to check for a 3x3x3 character 27 points and I needed to go even further since some creatures will be quite big I need them to be 5x5x5 for a total of 125 points being compared every frame when a character is moving and I also need to have quite a lot of characters on screen at the same time.

Now I am easily detecting the collision between characters by using Bounds.Intersects, however the collisions with the terrain feel quite messy, do I really have to calculate 125 points per frame against the terrain array or is there a better way?

Comment: I've never used it but Unity's ECM (DOTS) system is supposed to give you MASSIVE performance gains which looks like it will eat your processing for lunch :)  https://unity.com/dots

Comment: Sounds like a Minecraft world? You could try to create reduced arrays and keep 2:1 reduced versions of it, similar to using an octree. If your larger version of the map indicates that a 4*4*4 space is all empty, no need to iterate the subcubes one-by-one.

Another approach is a bitmap with just one bit per cube. It is compact, and you can check stretches of spaces in one masked check.